# How to trigger UIButton programmatically

Tags: swift

I want to trigger the IBAction method in another method

The button's IBOutlet is `currentButton`

I want to trigger the button in the `triggerTheButton` method

How to do it?

I don't know what action to call, what parameters should I have

```
func  triggerTheButton()->Void{

}

@IBOutlet var currentButton: UIButton!

self.currentButton.sendAction(<#action: Selector#>, to: <#AnyObject?#>, forEvent: <#UIEvent?#>)

@IBAction func showPrevious(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Comment: what about simply calling the `–triggerTheButton()` method?

Comment: If you dont need the sender (your Button) you can create a function in your class and call it from your IBAction.So you are able to call the same function everywhere in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Only a touch event can trigger the chain that causes handling an action this way. You can achieve this only by using a non-public API, which will lead to rejecting your app from the AppStore. If you're still interested in the topic I encourage you to analyse source of the [UI automatic tests framework on Github](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF).